# If condition based on previous row yields "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have loan data with borrower id, bank id, maturity date and date of loan disbursement. I would like to detect whether, for any borrower, her previous loan has not yet matured before the current one was disbursed (multiple borrowing). If so, I would like to generate a column that contains the bank id from which the previous, not yet matured loan, was taken out.

My data looks like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':[3,6,7,12,2,5,8,1],
              'borrower':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4],
              'bank':[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5],
              'maturity':[9,18,19,24,14,17,14,13]})
```

I would like to add to this one column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':[3,6,7,12,2,5,8,1],
              'borrower':[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4],
              'bank':[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5],
              'maturity':[9,18,19,24,14,17,14,13],
              'currently_borrowing':[np.nan,1,1,2,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

I have tried the following code:

```
df = df.sort_values(['borrower','month'])
if ((df['bank'] == df['bank'].shift()) & (df['maturity'] >= df['maturity'].shift()) &(df['maturity'].shift() > df['month'])) :
    df['currently_borrowing'] = df['bank'].shift()
else : 
    df['currently_borrowing'] = np.nan
```

but am getting the following error message:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I have tried adding `.any()` and `.all()` but then the new columns contains only NANs.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a mask and use `np.where`:

```
print(df)

   bank  borrower  maturity  month
0     1         1         9      3
1     1         1        18      6
2     2         1        19      7
3     3         1        24     12
4     3         2        14      2
5     3         2        17      5
6     4         3        14      8
7     5         4        13      1

df = df.sort_values(['borrower','month'])

mask = ((df['borrower'] == df['borrower'].shift()) 
       & (df['maturity'] >= df['maturity'].shift()) 
       & (df['maturity'].shift() > df['month']))

df['current borrow'] = np.where(mask, df.bank.shift(), np.nan)

print(df)

   bank  borrower  maturity  month  currentborrow
0     1         1         9      3            NaN
1     1         1        18      6            1.0
2     2         1        19      7            1.0
3     3         1        24     12            2.0
4     3         2        14      2            NaN
5     3         2        17      5            3.0
6     4         3        14      8            NaN
7     5         4        13      1            NaN
```

You are misunderstanding the applicability of `if...else` - it works with scalar values, not `pd.Series`. That's why `np.where` is more suited here.

In addition, you have issues with your mask logic. The first condition should've been done on the `borrower`, not the `bank`.